# multiple angular material table in single page pagination issue

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

i am using angular two material table in single html page. first table, data loaded well with proper pagination. but in second table, all data loading without pagination. i added pagination functionally to both pages. i would like to show some part of code regarding this.

### table 1 pagination (working well)

```
 <mat-paginator #paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

table 2 pagination (pagination not working)

```
  <mat-paginator #errorpaginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons>
```

my component file

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Input, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import { from } from 'rxjs/internal/observable/from';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { arInvoiceHeaderService} from './ar-invoice-header.service';
import { arInvoiceHeaderModel, arInvoiceHeader } from './ar-invoice-header-model';
import { MatSort, MatSortable, MatPaginator,MatTable, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import {animate, state, style, transition, trigger} from '@angular/animations';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { arErrorModel } from './ar-error-model';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-ar-invoice-header',
  templateUrl: './ar-invoice-header.component.html',
  animations: [
    trigger('detailExpand', [
      state('collapsed, void', style({height: '0px', minHeight: '0', display: 'none'})),
      state('expanded', style({height: '*'})),
      transition('* <=> *', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')),
    ]),
  ],
  styleUrls: ['./ar-invoice-header.component.css']
})
@Injectable()
export class ArInvoiceHeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
  //@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild('paginator') paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild('errorpaginator') errorpaginator: MatPaginator;
 @ViewChild(MatTable) table: MatTable<any>;
 
  isLoading = true;
  noGridData: boolean = false;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataSource);
  errordataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.errordataSource);
  //dataSource;
  //errordataSource;
  expandedElement: arInvoiceHeader;
  displayedColumns = ['id','invoiceNumber','status','orgName','setOfBooks','transactionSource','transactionType','errorCodeH','invoiceTotal','lineCount','interfaceFileLineNo','interfaceFileName','interfaceFilePath','createdBy','creationTimestamp'];
  errordisplayedColumns = ['id','invoiceNumber','lineNumber','interfaceFileName','interfaceFilePath','errorDescription'];


  constructor(private arinvoiceheaderService: arInvoiceHeaderService) {

   }

  ngOnInit() { 

    this.reloadList();
    this.arErrorList();
  }




//First table data loading function (currently working well with pagination )
  reloadList() {
    this.arinvoiceheaderService.getArInvoiceHeader().subscribe(results => {
      console.log(results);
      if (!results) {
       // return;
       alert("ERRor");
      }
    
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(results['ArInvoiceHeaders']);
      if(results.ArInvoiceHeaders.length > 0)
      {
       
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        this.isLoading = false;
        this.noGridData = false;
      }
      else{
        this.noGridData = true;
        this.isLoading = false;
      }
      
    });
  }

//seconf table data loading function (all data loading without pagination)
  arErrorList(){
    this.arinvoiceheaderService.getArErrorDetails().subscribe(results => {
      console.log(results);
      if (!results) {
        return;
      }
      this.errordataSource = new MatTableDataSource(results['ArInterfaceErrors']);

      this.errordataSource.errorpaginator = this.errorpaginator;
      this.errordataSource.sort = this.sort;


    });
  }
}
```

can you help me to sort out second table pagination issue.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz link with sample data?

Comment: is it difficult to find issue from this ?

Comment: HTML is missing from your question, also it will be easy to find the problem from stackblitz.

Comment: One thing that is definitely wrong is this: `this.errordataSource.errorpaginator = this.errorpaginator;`, it should read `this.errordataSource.paginator = this.errorpaginator;`. I assume when refactoring the variable you accidentally changed this property too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted in the comment this line of code here `this.errordataSource.errorpaginator = this.errorpaginator;` is wrong, there is no `errorpaginator` property on the datasource. It should be `this.errordataSource.paginator = this.errorpaginator;`.

See a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-ijhtyg?file=app/app.component.ts), if you uncomment the wrong line of code and comment the correct one you can see that it doesn't work with your code, but with the correct one it does.

Comment: in your code, you used  of(DATA2).pipe(delay(2500)). but my code using
this.arinvoiceheaderService.getArInvoiceHeader(). how i add your code to my solution.

Comment: big help if you can check .. :)

Comment: It is just to simulate an asynchronous request for data since I don't have access to your services to fetch data. Just replace `of(DATA2).pipe(delay(2500))` with your code `this.arinvoiceheaderService.getArInvoiceHeader()`. But all you really need to change in your code is this line `this.errordataSource.paginator = this.errorpaginator;`.

Comment: i changed it. but my second table load without pagination. pagination div also could not find.

Comment: is this essential code block for work this ??
of(DATA2).pipe(delay(2500))

Comment: No, it just simulates an async request. What happens if all you change in your original code is this line `this.errordataSource.errorpaginator = this.errorpaginator;` to this `this.errordataSource.paginator = this.errorpaginator;`?

Comment: i added this this.errordataSource.paginator = this.errorpaginator;
and change html view as  <mat-paginator #errorpaginator [pageSize]="10"
 [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]">
        </mat-paginator>

Comment: So the paginator in the second table is working properly now?

Comment: dear Fabian Kung, your code working well. but i did big mistake in my css file. i added 'max-height' to my table wrapper div. now all working well. thank your support. saved me

Answer (score 7):

multiple angular material table workd for me...

Table 1 pagination

```
 <mat-paginator [pageSize]="10" [pageSizeOptions]="[3, 5, 10]" 
  [showFirstLastButtons]="true"></mat-paginator>
```

Table 2 pagination

```
   <mat-paginator [pageSize]="10" #paginatorlist [pageSizeOptions]="[3, 5, 10]"  
    [showFirstLastButtons]="true"></mat-paginator>
```

TS: The change detector looks for the first element..So we can use property ..
read - True to read a different token from the queried elements.

```
    @ViewChild('paginatorlist', { read: MatPaginator }) paginatorlist: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**Table 1**

<mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 15, 20]" showFirstLastButtons>
</mat-paginator>

**Table 2**
<mat-paginator #modulePaginatpr [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 15, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>

**componenet.ts**
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild('modulePaginatpr') modulePaginatpr: MatPaginator;
```

For table1 (datasoure is sourse name in table 1 html code)
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;

```
For table2 (datasoure2 is sourse name in table 2 html code)
this.dataSource2.paginator = this.modulePaginatpr;
```